# Set up two external monitors on my laptop (aspire v3)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr, vga

Hi everyone i am going to buy two fullHD monitors and i would like to plug them into my laptop but i am not sure if this is possible. To be specific i have an *Acer Aspire V3-572G-76UP* that came with:

- NVIDIA GeForce 840M (actually there is also an Intel graphic embedded, but i use the nvidia)
- intel i7-5500U
- HDMI, VGA ports
- as OS i am running ubuntu 16.04

and i would like to add two of [this monitor](http://www.benq.com/product/monitor/gw2470h). HDMI and VGA cables should be enough for this task or my set up is not capable of such thing ?
Also, this is the output i get from *xrandr* :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected
HDMI-1 disconnected
HDMI-2 disconnected
```

The second problem is that i cannot see the vga output detected, 
thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 HDMI ports? We can see `HDMI-1` & `HDMI-2` in the xrandr output

Comment: No i only have one HDMI port

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of use you want from your monitors, if they're not for gaming/home cinema:

*"If you're aiming for three screens then look for USB to DVI adaptors, which are available for under £50. These will enable your laptop to generate a third video output, but will have an inherently low response time and are only suitable for more static content - not video."*

from here http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/peripherals/the-complete-guide-to-multiple-monitors-1074313

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm going to use these monitors just to improve the coding experience. Infact i will not need three monitors as i would turn off the laptop one keeping only the external ones.

Comment: Great - might be worth polling people's experience of these - I've not used them myself.

Answer (score 0):

If this will ever help someone : i finally bought and tried the monitors and it happened that they're working pretty well. I only got problems when switching through displays configurations : you have to connect sequentially the two monitors and then, if you want to, disable the built-in display; Otherwise you we'll be stuck with GPU problems,if that happens try to reboot without external connections, open terminal, run rm `~/.config/monitors.xml` reboot again and then follow the procedure as explained above.